# How do I get the max date and stage name for a certain value?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, salesforce, max

I am working on a query to pull the max date that is greater than a given period of time and have it return the value that is in that date. 
I'm working from a salesforce table and want to pull the max date that an opportunity is in and return the stage name that it is in. The date has to be greater than 5-1-14. So do I have to break this up into multiple queries? Give me the max date then return the stage name that its in. Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

```
SELECT OpportunityID,     

  Max(case when CREATEDDATE < '2014-05-01' THEN STAGENAME END) as Q1_FY15_Stage 

FROM [BVSFWarehouse].[dbo].[sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY]

GROUP by OPPORTUNITYID
```

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql", but the syntax is clearly SQL Server.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Sorry new to this, figured anyone with sql knowledge might have some good input.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause to limit the dates. Try:

```
SELECT
     OpportunityID
    ,STAGENAME
    ,MAX(CREATEDATE)
FROM BVSWarehouse.dbo.sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY
WHERE
    CREATEDATE > '2015-05-01'
GROUP BY
     OpportunityID
    ,STAGENAME
```

Comment: When I was checking the data it seems like the max created date isnt being pulled, instead im still getting all the dates in that range for the opportunity.  If I can have it return just the max date and the stage name it is in then that would be perfect. Any ideas or edits I would have to make to this query? So weird that the max function doesnt work on this as the logic makes sense.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the max *date* and just want whatever records it is attached to... What do you want to have happen if there are *multiple* records with the same, max date?

Comment: That is correct. I have a list of thousands of opportunities in Salesforce each with a unique opportunity ID assigned to it. So if multiple records have the same max date I still want it to return whatever stage that particular opportunity is in.  So say opportunity X went through scoping on 5-11-15, solution proposal on 5-11-15, and closed won 6-5-15. I want it to return only the stage it was in 6-5-15 which is closed won. Currently it is giving me all 3 results and stage names.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for confirming... What I mean is, what if it went through "solution proposal" *and* "closed won" on 6-5-15. I assume you would want it to show only "closed won"... If correct, this means you have a path/rank for the stages and only want to show the max stage achieved, which is not just date but also rank. What are all possible stages and their ranks?